# inscribed circle in $n$-gon

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons, plane-geometry

If I'm given a circle with radius $r$ and I want to create a polygon with side $n$ (say $n=5$) which can cover the circle fully,  then how to prove that a **regular** polygon is the solution with minimum area?

Comment: Hint: Find the area of a triangle which has one vertex at the origin and angle $\theta$ at the origin and is tangent to the circle (use a little trig).  Then, try to minimize the sum of $5$ such angles which add to $2\pi$.

Comment: You may be familiar with the proof (first part of [this previous Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/868065/3111)) that the polygon of given sides and maximum area is the cyclic one (the one which can be inscribed in circle).  I suspect a similar approach would work here, varying the placement of a single side to minimize the area outside the circle and equalize the corresponding interior angles of the circumscribed polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe without proof that a minimal area circumscribed $n$-gon exists you can argue as follows:

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three successive points of tangency with $\angle(AOB)=\alpha$, $\angle(BOC)=\beta$. Then  $\alpha+\beta<\pi$, and the polygonal area contained in the sector $AOC$ of central angle $\alpha+\beta$ is given by
$$\tan{\alpha\over2}+\tan{\beta\over2}={\sin{\alpha+\beta\over2}\over\cos{\alpha\over2}\cos{\beta\over2}}={2\sin{\alpha+\beta\over2}\over\cos{\alpha+\beta\over2}+\cos{\alpha-\beta\over2}}\ .$$
Keeping $A$ and $C$ (and with them $\alpha+\beta$) fixed this can be increased if $\alpha\ne\beta$. It follows that the smallest area $n$-gon has to be regular.

Comment: +1.  This method can be tweaked to prove the existence also.  By moving $B$, we can swap $\alpha$ and $\beta$; so wlog, $\alpha$ is the max and $\beta$ the min of such central angles.  If irregular, $\alpha > \frac{2\pi}{n} > \beta$; now, rather than replace $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with two copies of $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$, replace with $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and $\alpha+\beta-\frac{2\pi}{n}$.  Repeat; this terminates.  (I learned this trick from [Dijkstra's EWD1140](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD11xx/EWD1140.html).)